# Can I have multiple onStop methods in Android code?

Tags: java, android-studio

[image shows a screenshot of the app interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkeDU.png)I am very new to writing any kind of code, and am attempting to build an app that can host two podcasts. I want users to be able to play two separate podcasts on the app, and so need to use two separate onStop methods. However, I get the error:

> onStop()' is already defined in "app name"

Is there a way to implement 2 separate onStop methods?

```
package com.example.breastiesapp;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MindActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button button;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mind);
        mediaPlayer = null;

        //Body Button
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bodyBTN);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MindActivity.this,BodyActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //Home Button
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.homeBTN);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MindActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    //Play Pod 1
    public void PlayPod1(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPlayPod1:
                if (mediaPlayer ==  null) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.pod1feelmorejoy);
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        stopPod1();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case R.id.btnPausePod1:
                if (mediaPlayer !=null)
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                break;
            case R.id.btnStopPod1:
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    stopPod1();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void stopPod1() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopPod1();
    }
    //Play Pod 2
    public void PlayPod2(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnPlayPod2:
                if (mediaPlayer ==  null) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.usingmindfulnesstoreducestressandstrengthenyourimmune);
                }
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        stopPod2();
                    }
                });
                mediaPlayer.start();
                break;
            case R.id.btnPausePod2:
                if (mediaPlayer !=null)
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                break;
            case R.id.btnStopPod2:
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    stopPod2();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void stopPod2() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        stopPod1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need two `onStop()`? Why not just call `stopPod1()` and `stopPod2()` in the same `onStop()` implementation? But no, you cannot have two methods with the same exact signature in the same class. Also, note that Android Studio is only an IDE. It's not the IDE that's preventing you from doing this, it's the programming language (Java, in this case, though Kotlin has the same restrictions, as do many, if not most/all, other OOP languages).

Comment: Whenever you start creating `something1`, `something2`, etc., it's a good sign that you're missing an Object which will handle these things for you. These "pods" could have their own respective `#onStop`, which can handle cleanup for their own instances.

Comment: I have removed your second question. Please ask only one question per question. If you want the second question answered, ask a new, separate question.

Comment: Could you make a short demo of the current run by passing all the functions above so that we can understand what you need more clearly?

Comment: I am super new to coding, (first time making an app) so I don't know how to make a short demo. But I added an image of the interface to the question.